# Video camera view in videoViewController works on iPhone but not iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, viewcontroller

I have a bug in a Universal iOS app that does not display the camera view in the iPad frame. The view is offset to the left. The view sits perfectly in an iPhone, but not on iPad. The original code was written 2 years ago and I am wondering if there has been a change in iOS that is now missing from this section of code.

Here is what I have at the moment;

```
     self.preview = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:self.session];
AVCaptureConnection *avcc = [self.preview connection];
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
  [avcc setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight];
else
    [avcc setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight];
CGRect rect = [[[self view] layer] bounds];
[self.preview setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.height, rect.size.width)];
[self.preview setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidY(rect), CGRectGetMidX(rect))];
self.preview.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
```

Comment: `CGRect rect = [[[self view] layer] bounds];` , can you tell me whether `self.view` is full screen (using entire width and height) ?

Comment: where you are writing this piece of code?- viewDidLoad()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the problem , what I can suggest just add this line in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` if your project support Auto Layout .

**Code:-**

```
{
    CGRect bounds=self.view.layer.bounds;
    self.preview.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;  
    self.preview.bounds=bounds;
    self.preview.position=CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Problem solved. Swapped the statement order of the  rect.size.height and rect.size.width declarations as well as CGRectGetMidY(rect) and CGRectGetMidX(rect). Also added the CGRect bounds code. Thank you once again.